# How do I extract data from IDataObject in Win32 API

Tags: c#, winapi

## Context

### Long story

Hello!

I'm developing a SolidEdgde add-in which, among other things, is supposed to react to a dropped metadata file and after it has been dropped download all of the required files to the open them in the said CAD.

SolidEdge API does not expose a drag/drop event which would provide a simple solution to this problem. However, it does provide a general event which only notifies that an action with a given ID will be executed:

```cs
public void BeforeCommandRun(int theCommandID)
```

As you can clearly see I have no `DragEventArgs`. That is the reason why I decided to try and find a solution using Win32 API.

### TL;DR

I have access to a method which notifies me of a pre-drop; however, it doesn't provide `DragEventArgs`.

## What I have tried

### System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard

The following class does not provide dragged objects

### Win32

```cs
[DllImport("ole32")]
private static extern int OleGetClipboard(out IDataObject data);

public void BeforeCommandRun(int theCommandID)
{
    IEnumerable<FORMATETC> GetFormats(IEnumFORMATETC enumerable)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var formats = new FORMATETC[1];
            var count = new int[1];
            var x = enumerable.Next(1, formats, count);

            if (x == 0)
                yield return formats[0];

            break;
        }
    }

    switch (theCommandID)
    {
        case 42:
            var result = OleGetClipboard(out IDataObject data);
            var enumerable = data.EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR.DATADIR_GET);
            var formats = GetFormats(enumerable).ToList();

            data.GetData(formats.First(), out STGMEDIUM extract);

            var draggedObject = BlackMagic(extract); 

            break;
    }
}

private ??? BlackMagic(STGMEDIUM extract)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Using these methods I'm able to retrieve a medium I cannot work with. If I were to have the `System.Windows.IDataObject` instead of this Win32 API `IDataObject` everything would be fine.

### Checked the System.Windows.IDataObject

I figured that this class would wrap the Win32 API and would possibly have some sort of conversion logic. Unfortunately, I was unable to find anything like that. The class does call the Win32 API methods.

## My cry for help

1. Is this even the right way to do this?
2. If yes, how do I proceed?

It would be perfect if it would be possible to convert the Win32 DataObject to the System window one.

Thank you in advance for any help.

## Updates

### Update 1 (17.02.2020)

**Question from [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable)**:

> What about `SolidEdgeFramework.ISEApplicationWindowEvents`? Isn't that your entry to observe any window message?

No it is not. This exposes the WindowsProc event which has more event arguments; however, none of them are what I need.

**Question from [@Rita Han - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6601582/rita-han-msft)**:

> Which method do you want to use is invalid in Win32 IDataObject interface?

Thank you, the IntPtr documentation pushed me in the right direction. The methods I require are IDataObject.GetDataPresent(Type) and IDataObject.GetData(Type)

I will try to use some of the Marshall methods to extract my data.

Comment: What about `SolidEdgeFramework.ISEApplicationWindowEvents`? Isn't that your entry to observe *any* window message?

Comment: If you mean you don't how to handle `IntPtr` (`STGMEDIUM.unionmember`), you can refer to [`IntPtr` Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: And why do you want to **"convert the Win32 DataObject to the System window one"**? Which method do you want to use is invalid in Win32 [`IDataObject` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject)?

Comment: *"This exposes the WindowsProc event which has more event arguments; however, none of them are what I need."* - Are you sure? It sounds like you want to handle [WM_DROPFILES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/wm-dropfiles).